# Unable to manually close toggle panel

Tags: jquery

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/R5MPr/1/ - with a simple toggle panel. The toggle panel action works fine. You can click the questions and have the answers open and close. But the "Close All" button I have to manually close any open questions doesn't work. The

```
.slideToggle(500);
```

there doesn't close the open panel. Does anyone see the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: It appears to work for me in chrome

Comment: Note however there's a tiny bug. Try clicking on one of the panel headers 50 times really fast. Here's the fix to that tiny bug: http://jsfiddle.net/R5MPr/2/

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — **and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself**. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: @Kevin  Yes, it does indeed work now!  It was failing in jsfiddle and then I went back and edited it one last time to simplify it more by taking out some of the extra classes that got added and removed, but weren't relevant here. One of those must have had an extra space or something and was the problem. So coming here solved my problem, but sorry it wasn't more interesting for you guys. And thanks for the heads up on finish()!

Answer (score 1):

An easier way is to add a class to handle the closeAll.

HTML:

```
<div class="qa" id='qa'>
    <h3> This is question 1</h3>
    <div>This is  the answer to question 1</div>
     <h3> This is question 2</h3>
    <div>This is  the answer to question 2</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('button#closeAll').click(function() {
    $('.qa div').slideUp(500);  
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R5MPr/5/)

Comment: @Steve Looks that way. I had originally used slideToggle with this class, but it opened closed questions and closed open ones, living up to the 'toggle' functionality. `slideUp` effects only open questions and plays nice with ones that are already closed

Comment: Yes, that's MUCH easier. I would not have thought to try this, though, because I would have thought that the forced slideUp() would mess up the slideToggle() synchronization, but it doesn't, so apparently slideUp() is smart enough to flip the toggle state for slideToggle(). Is that what's happening?  (I deleted and readded this comment, so it actually belongs before Brian's comment above.)

Comment: Actually, looking more at it, there is no toggle state variable. slideToggle() just looks at the current state of the element and switches to the opposite state.  So the forced slideUp() causes slideToggle to find the Up state, and act appropriately.